# Angular 2 - Possibility to override default binding behavior for null values

Tags: angular, binding

Is it possible in Angular 2 - 6 to override the default binding/interpolation behavior for null values.

For example,

```
{{ null }} // gives ''
```

I want to override this behavior such that `{{ null }}` resolves to `"NA"` or `"-"` in the HTML.

PS: I am aware of the common way to achieve this like `{{ null || 'NA' }}` but I want a centralized solution for this.

UPDATE:

Pipes is a definitely a better solution than using the *or* operator but it will require the same amount of code duplication/noise as above. `{{ null | NAPipe }}` is as noisy as `{{ null || 'NA' }}`.

Comment: Do you want to avoid using pipes too?

Comment: Yes. Although pipes is centralized solution, it will required same amount of code duplication in the components.

Comment: just add this to your `ngOnChanges` in the component `Object.keys(this).forEach((key)=>this[key] = this[key] === null ? 'NA' : this[key])`. I'm sure there are many other ways to waste time trying to save yourself time.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're downvoted. The question seems specific enough, and frameworks often do provide hooks to override something globally.

Comment: @FrankModica Angular does not provide any hooks for how it handles expression parsing. You have `pipes` and methods from the component. He doesn't appear to want that. So there can be no correct Answer. Downvoting saves other people time so they can avoid posting answers he won't accept.

Comment: @cgTag But the question is reasonable, plus how do we know for sure there will be no answer? What if Angular provides a way to do this in the future, or someone comes up with a clever hack?

Comment: @FrankModica stackoverflow allows you to reverse your down votes after the question has been edited. I can't write the question for him. If he improves it I'll then up vote accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your views about the question @FrankModica.

Comment: @cgTag - I have made an update to the question to mention what I am exactly looking for. I don't worry if my question is downvoted as I am not here for votes, I am here to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a pipe that will give the display value for your data (ex- null here)

The pipe will return 'NA' when value is null.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'displayFormatter' })
    export class DisplayFormatterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value: any): string {
        switch (value) {
            case null:
                return 'NA'
                break;
            case ... // complete the code   
        }       
    }
}
```

and in your html

```
{{value | displayFormatter}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like yo use pipes please return a display value from the method that's generating these value

```
yourFunction(): any {
    ....
    return this.formatValue(yourValue); // Implement formatValue to generate display value
}
```

Comment: If he didn't want to use pipes because of code duplication, I'd think he wouldn't want to do this everywhere either.

Comment: But my answer can be taken into consideration (at least by another person having a similar problem) and if he has only one or minimal   **yourFunction()** like methods. he can minimize duplication